# Use wpf toolset in class library

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit

I am referencing wpf toolset nuget package from the class lib project. But whenever I am applying a custom template / control it throwing exception with "could not find wpf toolset" ..any idea to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added something like `xmlns:wpfTool="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit"` to your xaml?

Comment: @user3675707 Then I think we need to see some code to be able to determine what the problem might be.

Comment: I figured out this by referencing genric.xaml to resource dictionary as merge dictionary. Now it's working fine for me. Thanks for your reply.